# Metaclass Singletons Not Working

Tags: python, singleton, metaclass

I've tried recently to add a singleton to my project, but it doesn't act like I'd think it would.
The code looks somewhat like this:

**main/main.py**

```
class main(metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self):
        ....
    def Action(self):
        self.helper=otherclasses.other.other()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = main()
    m.Action()
```

**main/metaclasses/singleton.py**

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instance = None
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dict):
        super(Singleton, cls).__init__(name, bases, dict)

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance 

    def Instance(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return cls.__call__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**main/otherclasses/other.py**

```
class other():
     def __init__(self):
         ...
         self.main = Main.Instance()
         ...
```

so, as far as I understand this concept - I should have got the same instance of Main for subclass. Yet I get a whole new Main object. 
I'd be glad for some help! What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you find out that `Main.Instance()` returns a new object? Also why is `subclass` called subclass when it is not a subclass?

Comment: Main prints logs in it's __init__ function, which are being printed again whenever I call it from otherclass
Also, subclass isn't called subclass, I've named it that for this post only. Bad name choosing, edited

Comment: You must have changed something else when copying your code to this question. I copied it (changing lowercase `singleton` to uppercase) and every attempt at instanciating `main` or calling `main.Instance()` resulted in the exact same object. Oh and i also indented `singleton.py` correctly`

Comment: Well, I've fixed it and posted an answer. I guess you've ran it appropriately and not through "main.py" as I did, thus it worked for you.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

I believe that the reason for the problem was that I ran the program through "# python main.py". This way, because **main.py** wasn't loaded as a module, when **other.py** called **"import main"**, it was re-loaded, and thus **Main** re-initialized **Singleton**.

Moving the *"Run"* function to another file (*"# python Run.py"*) and importing main.py from there, thus only initializing **Singleton** (and **Main**) only once as I wanted to.

Thank you all :)

Comment: `python main.py` runs `main.py` as a module: the `__main__` module. I'm not sure how you did it thoug. You ran `python main.py` and `other.py` imported main? How is that possible? Also no module will be re-loaded, they are all cached.

Comment: By reading sys.modules I could see that in running `python main.py` I get `Main` twice: once from `__main__` and one from `main.py`. By moving it out to `python run.py`, I only got it once.
About `other.py` importing main: I need main to dynamically load modules from some source, using `importlib.import_module(mod)`. This way, when `other.py` imports main - it doesn't re-import itself and crash.